# Filter out a expression from Regex match

Tags: regex, filter

I have a regex query which works fine for most of the input patterns but few.
Regex query I have is

```
("(?!([1-9]{1}[0-9]*)-(([1-9]{1}[0-9]*))-)^(([1-9]{1}[0-9]*)|(([1-9]{1}[0-9]*)( |-|( ?([1-9]{1}[0-9]*))|(-?([1-9]{1}[0-9]*)){1})*))$")
```

I want to filter out a certain type of expression from the input strings i.e except for the last character for the input string every dash (-) should be surrounded by the two separate integers i.e (integer)(dash)(integer).

Two dashes sharing 3 integers is not allowed even if they have integers on either side like `(integer)(dash)(integer)(dash)(integer)`.

If the dash is the last character of input preceded by the integer that's an acceptable input like `(integer)(dash)(end of the string)`.

Also, two consecutive dashes are not allowed. Any of the above-mentioned formats can have space(s) between them.

To give the gist, these dashes are used in my input string to provide a range.
Some example of expressions that I want to filter out are

> `1-5-10`, `1 - 5 - 10`, `1 - - 5`, `-5`

Update - There are some rules which will drive the input string. My job is to make sure I allow only those input strings which follow the format. Rules for the format are -
 1. Space (‘ ‘) delimited numbers. But dash line doesn’t need to have a space. For example, “10 20 - 30” or “10 20-30” are all valid values.
 2. A dash line (‘-‘) is used to set range (from, to). It also can used to set to the end of job queue list. For example, “100-150 200-250 300-“ is a valid value.
3. A dash-line without start job number is not allowed. For example, “-10” is not allowed.

Thanks

Comment: can you post your input string?

Comment: @The Scientific Method - There are some rules which will drive the input string. My job is to make sure I allow only those input strings which follow the format.
Rules for the format are - 
1. Space (‘ ‘) delimited numbers. But dash line doesn’t need to have a space. For example, “10 20 - 30” or “10 20-30” are all valid values.
2. A dash line (‘-‘) is used to set range (from, to).  It also can used to set to the end of job queue list. For example, “100-150 200-250 300-“ is a valid value. 
3. A dash-line without start job number is not allowed. For example, “-10” is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use:

`^(?:(?:[1-9][0-9]*[ ]?-[ ]?[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*)(?: (?:[1-9][0-9]*[ ]?-[ ]?[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*))*(?: [1-9][0-9]*-)?|[1-9][0-9]*-?)[ ]*$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UsMoso/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[1-9][0-9]*[ ]?-[ ]?[1-9][0-9]*` Match number > 0, an optional space, a dash, an optional space and number > 0. *The space is in a character class `[ ]` for clarity*.
    - `|` Or
    - `[1-9][0-9]*` Match number > 0
  - `)` Close non capturing group
  - `(?:[ ]` Non capturing group followed by a space

    - `(?:` Non capturing group

      - `[1-9][0-9]*[ ]?-[ ]?[1-9][0-9]*` Match number > 0, an optional space, a dash, an optional space and number > 0.
      - `|` Or
      - `[1-9][0-9]*` Match number > 0
    - `)` close non capturing group
  - `)*` close non capturing group and repeat zero or more times
  - `(?: [1-9][0-9]*-)?` Optional part that matches a space followed by a number > 0
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9][0-9]*-?` Match a number > 0 followed by an optional dash
- `)` close non capturing group
- `[ ]*$` Match zero or more times a space and assert the end of the string

**Note**If you want to match zero or more times a space instead of an optional space, you could update `[ ]?` to `[ ]*`. You can write `[1-9]{1}` as `[1-9]`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Very close. Only one issue with this response is with the trailing dash at the end of the string.  Integer preceding the ending dash should not be used with any other dash. For example, it will accept "10 20-25-" however since 25 is already used for end range with the preceding dash, it cannot be used for trailing dash. For this case, acceptable input would be like "10 20-25 30-". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. Also, thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Keep in mind that it currently doesn't match `"123-"` it requires one decimal or range to be before it. eg. `"1 123-"` and `"1-1 123-"` do both work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. That's a requirement. "123-" is an acceptable value. Can you please update the response to include that as well? By the way is it possible to allow a trailing whitespace at the end of the input string?

Comment: @AkshatS This [updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/UsMoso/1) will match trailing whitespace at the end and it will also match `123-`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much @The fourth bird.

Answer (score 0):

After the update the question got quite a lot of complexity. Since some parts of the regex are reused multiple times I took the liberty of working this out in Ruby and cleaned it up afterwards. I'll show you the build process so the regex can be understood. Ruby uses `#{variable}` for regex and string interpolation.

```
integer = /[1-9][0-9]*/
integer_or_range = /#{integer}(?: *- *#{integer})?/
integers_or_ranges = /#{integer_or_range}(?: +#{integer_or_range})*/
ending = /#{integer} *-/
regex = /^(?:#{integers_or_ranges}(?: +#{ending})?|#{ending})$/
#=> /^(?:(?-mix:(?-mix:(?-mix:[1-9][0-9]*)(?: *- *(?-mix:[1-9][0-9]*))?)(?: +(?-mix:(?-mix:[1-9][0-9]*)(?: *- *(?-mix:[1-9][0-9]*))?))*)(?: +(?-mix:(?-mix:[1-9][0-9]*) *-))?|(?-mix:(?-mix:[1-9][0-9]*) *-))$/
```

Cleaning up the above regex leaves:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]*(?: *- *[1-9][0-9]*)?(?: +[1-9][0-9]*(?: *- *[1-9][0-9]*)?)*(?: +[1-9][0-9]* *-)?|[1-9][0-9]* *-)$
```

You can replace `[0-9]` with `\d` if you like, but since you used the `[0-9]` syntax in your question I used it for the answer as well. Keep in mind that if you do replace `[0-9]` with `\d` you'll have to escape the backslash in string context. eg. `"[0-9]"` equals `"\\d"`

You mention in your question that

> Any of the above-mentioned formats can have space(s) between them.

I assumed that this means space(s) are not allowed before or after the actual content, only between the integers and `-`.

- Valid:

  `15    - 10`

  `1234        -`
- Invalid:

  `15 - 10`

  `123`

If this is not the case simply add  `*` to the start and end.

```
^ *... *$
```

Where `...` is the rest of the regex.

You can test the regex in my [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZaDDdk/5), but it should be clear from the build process what the regex does.

```js
var
inputs = [
  '1-5-10',
  '1 - 5 - 10',
  '1 - - 5',
  '-5',
  '15-10',
  '15 - 10',
  '15      -          10',
  '1510',
  '1510-',
  '1510       -',
  '1510    ',
  '   1510',
  '  15 - 10',
  '10 20 - 30',
  '10 20-30',
  '100-150 200-250 300-',
  '100-150 200-250 300- ',
  '1-2526-27-28-',
  '1-25 26-2728-',
  '1-25 26-27 28-',
],

regex = /^(?:[1-9][0-9]*(?: *- *[1-9][0-9]*)?(?: +[1-9][0-9]*(?: *- *[1-9][0-9]*)?)*(?: +[1-9][0-9]* *-)?|[1-9][0-9]* *-)$/,

logInputAndMatch = input => {
  console.log(`input: "${input}"`);
  console.log(input.match(regex))
};

inputs.forEach(logInputAndMatch);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your solution helps me match the expression I have mentioned in the original question but then it breaks the patterns which were already matching. I should have listed the all the allowed patterns in my original question. I have added them to the comment above.

Comment: @AkshatS I updated my answer. I still wasn't sure about the prefixed/trailing spaces, so I left that part the same.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Almost close. Only one issue with this response is it is accepting the inputs where each dash is not surrounded by 2 separate double-digit integers example it is accepting 1-25-26-27-28-....... What's interesting is it will not accept the same format when first of those 2 digit integers is converted to the single digit integer, example it will behave right and not accept 1-5-25. Summarizing the issue it will accept "1-25-" and not "1-5-". prefixed/trailing spaces are ok to have. Appreciate your help and efforts, Johan.

Comment: @AkshatS You're correct I had `[ ]*` between decimals or ranges, this should've been `[ ]+` since the space is mandatory. The same goes for the ending. If this explanation is not clear have a look at [the diff of revision 7](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52521616/revisions).

Comment: Thank you @Johan for the explanation. Wish I could upvote your response but since I am a newbie, I am not eligible for an upvote. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @AkshatS np. After the question update it became a lot more clear what your overall intention was and what the input might look like. In its current state it deserves my upvote.